# How to ask to enter valid exist email id from user

Tags: android

Hi guys I am working on android application in which user have to register via email.

I can fetch the email id using `AccountManager` & disable the edittext so that user can't edit it. But this creates a big problem that user can't use any other email other than configured email on mobile .

I am doing this because user should not be able to register with our system if he enters spam email which doesn't exist.

Is there any good approach to handle this situation instead of disable email edittext.

I know email verification can be done by sending pin to user email & ask user to enter but this is where user have to go to gmail app from my app then from gmail to my app or this is only way for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already experienced, your chosen mechanism simply won't work because what happens if the user doesn't have an email registered on the device? What if the user has multiple accounts on the device?

Like millions of sites and apps on the Internet, why change an excellent method of ensuring a valid email by sending a confirmation email with an activation mechanism when the user proves they can access the email they registered with?

If the user has the email account on their phone then within a few moments they can activate their account from the same device and they're done.

As a user I would feel very unsure of an app that "assumed" an email address I would want to use to register. Let me put my own in. If I own the account I'll get the activation link.

Comment: What if I use Login via Google instead of verify email by sending activation link. But if I use login via Google  then Some people will think that this app will try to do wrong in case of new users which are new in mobile technology. What you say ??

Comment: When designing your app you need to specify what information your app will require access to. If people are comfortable with it then they will use it.